# Nested Transformer Laravel 5 return "dirty json"

Tags: php, json, laravel

In my Laravel 5 app I've used Fractal and Transformers. In one response I nested two object transformed with Trasnformers.

Here's my code:

```
public function transform(UserLogin $userLogin)
{
    $fractal = new Manager();
    $fractal->setSerializer(new ArraySerializer());
    $user = new Item($userLogin->user, new UserTransformer);
    return [
        "token" => $userLogin->token,
        "user" => $fractal->createData($user)->toJson()
    ];
}
```

and here's User Trasnformer transform:

```
public function transform(User $user)
{
    return [
        'id'=> $user->id,
        'name' => $user->firstname." ".$user->lastname,
        'email' => $user->email,
    ];
}
```

And in my controller I return like this:

```
return Fractal::item($userLogin, new UserLoginTransformer)->responseJson(200);
```

Here's the response from server:

```
 {
  "token": "the_token_generated",
  "user": "{\\\"id\\\":1,\\\"name\\\":\\\"Name\\\",\\\"email\\\":\\\"myemail@myemail.com\\\"}"
}
```

What am I getting wrong to show all these slashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encoding twice:

```
return [
    "token" => $userLogin->token,
    "user" => $fractal->createData($user)->toJson()
];
```

Note that the `user` key contains a json string as you have encoded it with `toJson()`.

Now when you encode your end result, you will encode that json string and that leads to the string:

```
"{\\\"id\\\":1,\\\"name\\\":\\\"Name\\\",\\\"email\\\":\\\"myemail@myemail.com\\\"}"
```

You should not encode the partial results, only the end result:

```
return [
    "token" => $userLogin->token,
    "user" => $fractal->createData($user)
];
```

**Edit:** Based on your comment you would need:

```
return [
    "token" => $userLogin->token,
    "user" => $fractal->createData($user)->toArray()
];
```

Comment: It returns {} and no data in "user" key

Comment: @Bellots What does the `createData()` method return? Perhaps you need something like `toObject()` instead of `toJson()` to return the actual information.

Comment: It's Fractal's method, and it accepts only toJson() or toArray()

Comment: @Bellots `toArray()` it is then :-)

Comment: I thought that toArray() was only for collection, it worked :) thank you!!